# Passing data through 3rd party react components

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following react component structure:

- MyEditor

  - Bootstrap Tabs

    - Component Grid

      - Image 1
      - Image 2
      - Image x

In the myEditor component I have a function componentSelected() which sets the state. In an app where I've written every component I just pass the componentSelected() function as a prop through the tree of components and call it from the image object.

`componentSelected={this.props.componentSelected}`

However, in this app I'm using a 3rd party component. Bootstrap tabs to be precise. How do I pass my componentSelected() function through the 3rd party component to it's children so they can invoke it?

This leads a separate question. Am I misunderstanding React? Can I call a function up the React component tree without passing it down to the component as a prop? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does the 3rd party component fit into your tree? Also remember that you can pass a component as a child of another one (`<Parent><Child /></Parent>`).

Comment: The bootstrap tab is my 3rd party component. Am I right is saying that you can't call a function on a grandparent in React? You MUST pass any function down the tree as a prop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, the [convention](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) is top-to-bottom through `props`, so you'd do something like in your render method in MyEditor:

`<BootstrapTabs>
  <ComponentGrid componentSelected={this.props.componentSelected}>
  ...
  </ComponentGrid>
</BootstrapTabs>`

EDIT: You can absolutely add extra props to your BootstrapTabs without changing the source, but you might as well save yourself that extra level of prop-passing unless your selection action occurs at that level.